# Inverses of elements in group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group whose elements are $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ and let $F$ be the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. We define a vector space over $F$ with $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ as a basis, and we call this vector space $FG$, and all the elements in $FG$ have the form $$\lambda_1g_1 + \cdots  + \lambda_ng_n \quad(\text{all }\lambda_i \in F)$$

Now the vector space $FG$ is the group algebra of $G$ over $F$. And it also known that the identity element under multiplication in $FG$ is $1e$ where $1$ is the identity in $F$ and $e$ is the identity element in $G$.

> My question is: given an element in the group algebra $FG$, can we
>   find the inverse of that element (construct it explicitly)?

For example, let $$G = C_3 = \bigl\langle a: a^3 = 1 \bigr\rangle$$ be the cyclic group of order $3$, and let $F = \mathbb{R}$. Now let $u = a + a^2 \in FG$. Now I want to know what is the inverse of $u$, meaning that I want to find an element $v \in FG$ such that $uv =e =vu$. More formally, we need to find $$v= \lambda_1e + \lambda_2a + \lambda_3a^2$$ such that $uv=e=vu$, so I just multiply $$\begin{align*}
uv &= (a + a^2)(\lambda_1e + \lambda_2a + \lambda_3a^2) \\
&= \lambda_1a + \lambda_2a^2 + \lambda_3e + \lambda_1a^2 + \lambda_2e + \lambda_3a \\
&= \lambda_1(a + a^2) + \lambda_2(a^2 +e) + \lambda_3(e + a)
\end{align*}$$

But now what is the next step, I need $e + e + e = e$ but how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you grouped $uv$ as $(\lambda_2 + \lambda_3)e + (\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)a + (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)a^2$, which you want to be $1e + 0a + 0a^2$.

Comment: I feel I should point out that is not true that every nonzero element of the group algebra is invertible.

Comment: This element is though. Its inverse is $\frac{1}{2}(1-(a+a^2))$.

Comment: @Nate Can you give me an example for a group $G$,Field $F$ where $FG$ has a non invertible element  ??

Comment: @alkabary In this very group ring the element $1a-1e$ is not invertible, as $(1a-1e)(1a^2+1a+1e)=1a^3-1e=0$.

Comment: @Nate Can you give me an example where $FG$ has a non invertible element !

Comment: More generally, for the group ring of any nontrivial finite group, for any nonidentity element $x$ we have that $1x-1e$ is a zero divisor because if the element is of order $n$ then $1x^n-1e=(1x-1e)(1x^{n-1}+1x^{n-2}+\cdots+1e)=0$.

Comment: For every nontrivial finite group $G$, it is true that $\mathbb{C}G$ has zero divisors.

Comment: But for a specific example, let $X$ be the sum of all group elements.  $X$ multiplied by anything else in the group algebra gives a multiple of $X$, so it can't be invertible.

Comment: for $x^5 = e$ we have $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)(1-x) = 0$ right @MattSamuel

Comment: $x^5 = e$ @MattSamuel

Comment: Yes. If $x=e$ this is trivial, but otherwise $x$ is of order  $5$ so this is a product on two nonzero elements.

Comment: @MattSamuel 
How come we can talk about an identity with some of the elements not having inverse ?

Comment: @alkabary The ring of integers has an identity but only $\pm 1$ have multiplicative inverses. This is typical; a ring is very special if every nonzero element has an inverse (it is a field).

Answer (score 4):

Note that not every element has an inverse, as some are zero divisors. This element, however, does.

Note that 
$$(a+a^2)^2=a^2+2a^3+a^4=a+a^2+2e$$
so
$$(a+a^2)^2-(a+a^2)=2e$$
so
$$(a+a^2)(1-(a+a^2))=2e$$
hence
$$(a+a^2)\left(\frac{1}{2}(1-(a+a^2))\right)=e$$
so the inverse is
$$\frac{1}{2}(1-(a+a^2))$$

In general, left multiplication of an element $y=\sum_{g\in G}{a_gg}$ by an element $x=\sum_{h\in G}{b_hg}$ with unknown coefficients and setting it equal to $1e$ yields a system of equations, which we can solve for $b_h$ if the element is invertible. We have
$$\sum_{gh=g'}{a_gb_hg'}=1e$$
so we need to solve
$$\sum_{gh=g'\neq e}{a_gb_h}=0$$
and
$$\sum_{gh=e}{a_gb_h}=1$$
If this system has a solution, then $\sum_h{b_hh}$ is a left inverse for $y$. By symmetry of the roles of $g$ and $h$ in the summation, the element will also be a right inverse.